# An exponential "rearrangement" inequality: $x^x+y^y>x^y+y^x$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $x,y$ be distinct real numbers greater than $0$. Prove
>
> $$x^x+y^y>x^y+y^x .$$

**Source:** I think it comes from a Russian test given in 1991, but I haven't been able to verify this.

Comment: see:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410895/inequality-with-exponents/410954#410954

Comment: There is a long ML thread about this and related ones at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=118722

Comment: @Nirbhay: This Question deals with strict inequality, while the proposed duplicate does on the weak inequality.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah you are right...